# Getting attribute of xml child nodes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, attr

I had to amend this question because I left out a piece of code that breaking things. I only want to look at the images for a certain church.

xml file:

```
<churches>
<church>
        <data-name>germanevangelical</data-name>
        <name>German Evangelical</name>
        <address>501 Elm St.</address>
        <opened>1887</opened>
        <neighborhood>East</neighborhood>
        <region>East</region>
        <architecture>Gothic</architecture>
        <denomination>Evangelical Lutheran</denomination>
        <closed>2006</closed>
        <image caption="Mary Smith">image_1_forweb.jpg</image>
        <image caption="Mary Smith">image_2_forweb.jpg</image>
        <image caption="Mary Smith">image_3_forweb.jpg</image>
</church>
... (more church nodes)
</churches>
```

I want to access the image captions with jQuery.

Here is my code, but it's returning "undefined" for the captions:

```
var cName = 'germanevangelical';  
$.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "churchdata.xml",
              dataType: "xml",
              success: function(xml) {
                var name = $(xml).find("data-name"); //get church names from xml file
                $(name).each(function(id, item) {
                    if ($(item).text() == cName) { //find the right church in the xml file
                        $(item).parent().find("image").each(function(id, node) {
                            console.log('id: ' + $(node).attr('caption'));//undefined
                        })
                    }//end if right church in xml file
                })
              }
            });
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Is `xml` already parsed as `#document` where `dataType` is set to `xml`? Also missing closing `)` at `.each()`

Comment: OK, I am an idiot. I did not have attributes written for the church I kept clicking. I had attributes for the church above it. Human error can't be underestimated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very small mistake in your ajax code while parsing, use $xml instead of $(xml) while finding "data-name". Please check below code.. Try to run your page in chrome and check if any errors in the developer tools, if there is any errors it wont work.

```
var cName = 'germanevangelical';  
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url: "churchdata.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var name = $xml.find("data-name"); //get church names from xml file
        $(name).each(function(id,item) {
              if ($(item).text() == cName) {
                $(item).parent().find("image").each(function(id,node) { 
                    console.log('id: ' + $(node).attr('caption')); //undefined
                });
               }
        });
      }
 });
```

Comment: This didn't make a difference in the results, but thank you.

Comment: Can you try copy paste my code and try.. there is few type errors in your code as well.

Comment: The answer above yours worked, but when I added code to see whether the church name matched a variable, I could no longer access the attributes of "image".

Comment: Your code works. I did a stupid thing and was looking at the wrong church, which had no captions.

Answer (score 0):

`$.parseXML()` is not necessary, where `dataType` at `$.ajax()` is set to `"xml"` an `XMLDocument` should be returned as `xml` at `success` of `$.ajax()` call.

Note also, missing closing `)` at `.each()` calls at `javascript` at Question.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "churchdata.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    console.log(xml);
    var name = $(xml).find("data-name"); //get church names from xml file
    $(name).each(function(id, item) {
      $(item).parent().find("image").each(function(id, node) {
        console.log('id: ' + $(node).attr('caption'));
      })
    })
  }
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/HYaaxN0EY0JtkciBMJpl?p=preview

Comment: This worked until I put in my code to see if the church matched my variable (see above). Now the attributes aren't being returned. Any idea why please?

Comment: @LauraNMS _"This worked until I put in my code to see if the church matched my variable (see above). Now the attributes aren't being returned. Any idea why please?"_ Can you fork plnkr to demonstrate? Appears to return expected result at version 2 of plnkr

Comment: Problem was that I didn't put captions in that node of my xml! Stupid human error. Thank you for your help!